What is the name of this bush?
I could not find it by googleing, my Smartphone does not recognize it and my local garden shop could also not identify it.
But his bush is quite popular in Germany and I know the plant by its look  and smell since I was a kid.
Does anyone know its name?
The images were taken two weeks ago in the mid of April in the mid west of Germany.



It's a spirea, probably a Spirea x vanhouttei cultivar; it's called Bridal Wreath in the US. If I'm correct, the flowers will have a somewhat unpleasant smell. It could also be a different white-flowered spirea species, such as Tor Birchleaf Spirea (Spirea betulifolia); the flowers of this species don't have much of a scent.

Yes, it is! Thank you very much! Here in Germany the "Prachtspiere" and the "Rispenspiere" are popular. There are many variants, I learnt a lot, if someone searches for shops in Germany, add "Spirea x vanhouttei" to the names I mentioned above to get one like the one on my photos.
